# How to embed auxiliary Snakemake workflows into main workflow structure

Tags: python, design-patterns, bioinformatics, snakemake

The [Snakemake documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html) defines how to setup the directory structure of a workflow. This is useful for easier understanding and deployment using [snakedeploy](https://github.com/snakemake/snakedeploy).

My question is how to embed auxiliary workflows, which are functionally tightly connected to the main workflow but fulfill a different goal, with this approach. We would, for example, want to do this with [V-pipe](https://github.com/cbg-ethz/V-pipe), where the main workflow processes sequencing data, and auxiliary workflows would download sequencing data or run a tool benchmark.

The following approaches come to mind:

- store all auxiliary workflows in external git repositories. This would be a clean solution (and snakedeploy could readily be used) but adds the overhead of having to maintain multiple code sources.
- integrate the auxiliary workflows into the main workflow. This would make the main workflow more complex and is not always feasible.
- put all auxiliary workflows into 'resources/auxiliary_workflows/'. This would allow all workflows to live in a single codebase while not unnecessarily increasing complexity of the main workflow. However, deploying the auxiliary workflows would be slightly more complicated.

Do you have a suggestion which of these approaches would be best suited for our needs, or have an entirely different approach in mind?

Comment: Could your solutions 1 and 3 be merged, using git submodules?

Comment: That's indeed exactly what we had in mind with the:

> deploying the auxiliary workflows would be slightly more complicated.

Comment: I see 2 way we could be doing this:

First way would be:
Auxilary workflows in separate snakedeploy-able repos that in turn have the main repo as a submodule and tap into the corresponding files.

e.g.: there is a V-pipe_download repos, that is itself a thin snakedeploy wrapper around V-pipe that just load the correct config and Snakefile.

It's easy to maintain for us (V-pipe is still a single package) and easy to deploy, but not necessarily aesthetically pleasing (the thin wrapper).

Comment: The other was would be: Each workflow has its own dedicated repository, and that one is included in the main V-pipe repos a sub-module.
snakedeploy gets more elegant.
But handling sub-modules require a tiny bit more work.